# How to create LablePoint from DataFrame directly without hardcoding the each column index of the dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have dataframe(inputDF) with 100 columns with decimal data type. I want to created LabelPoint using the dataframe(inputDF).

I am able to create the LablePoint by hardcoding the each column index of the dataframe, which is not the optimal solution.

```
val outputLabelPoint = inputDF.map(x => new LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.dense(x.getAs[Double](0),x.getAs[Double](1),x.getAs[Double](2),x.getAs[Double](3), ...))
```

How to create LablePoint from DataFrame directly without hardcoding the each column index of the dataframe?

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[VectorAssembler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler) may be the transformer you wanna find.

VectorAssembler is a transformer that combines a given list of columns into a single vector column.

id | hour | mobile | userFeatures     | clicked
----|------|--------|------------------|---------
0  | 18   | 1.0    | [0.0, 10.0, 0.5] | 1.0

**AFTER**

id | hour | mobile | userFeatures     | clicked | features
----|------|--------|------------------|---------|-----------------------------
0  | 18   | 1.0    | [0.0, 10.0, 0.5] | 1.0     | [18.0, 1.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.5]

I am confused why the two tables cannot display correctly.

Refer to the example in the [Spark Doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler) for more details.

If you want more help, please describe your column names and how they are generated.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Could you please explain me in detail?

Comment: I am using RandomForestModel in the MLlib(Spark 1.6.1). I have 100+ features as columns in the input dataframe like userId|feature1|feature2|feature3|feature4|feature5|feature6|.. except userId column other columns are numeric(decimal). model.predict method take LabeledPoint as input, LabeledPoint has two parts, one is label, another one is features. So I need to prepare the LabeledPoint from input dataframe, which can be feed into the model.predict method. Help would be appreciated.